# Python - Can't figure out how to re-run my program

Tags: python

I have been having trouble trying to figure out how to re-execute this code. Nothing I have found has worked. If there is a way to do it without completely rewriting it that would be great. It took me a good amount of time just to get this to work at all.

```
def oddsquare(numbers):
for n in numbers:
    if n % 2 == 1:
        print n**2,
else:
    return ""

startingnumber1 = int(raw_input('Enter your starting number:'))
endingnumber = int(raw_input('Enter your ending number:')) + 1

list1 = range(startingnumber1, endingnumber)
oddsquare(list1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by re-run? Does it not work at all?

Comment: Your indentation is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a lot more easier if you defined re-run, but you could just place it all in a while loop, like so:

```
def oddsquare(numbers):
    for n in numbers:
        if n % 2 == 1:
            print n**2
        else:
            return ""
while True:
    startingnumber1 = int(raw_input('Enter your starting number:'))
    endingnumber = int(raw_input('Enter your ending number:')) + 1
    list1 = range(startingnumber1, endingnumber)
    oddsquare(list1)
```

if you need to stop the loop you simply use "break".

Also, as the person in the comments mentions, no need for the else, that will actually break your code, because it will return nothing if it's not equal to one, so unless it's divisble with every number, it will fail.

Comment: This is a correct answer, but the else isn't necessary.  oddsquare prints and returns None, except the else makes it return the empty string which is pointless

Answer (score 1):

I think you are at a very beginner level. And assuming this I'll answer you.
When you return from the else statement, the loop ends, that's why you feel to "re-run" it

Corrected Code

```
def oddsquare(numbers):
    for n in numbers:
        if n % 2 == 1:
            print n**2

startingnumber1 = int(raw_input('Enter your starting number:'))
endingnumber = int(raw_input('Enter your ending number:')) + 1

list1 = range(startingnumber1, endingnumber)
oddsquare(list1)
```

I'll suggest you one more thing, one my behalf, if you are not using python3 and above, 
To input integers you can use `input()` instead of `raw_input()`.

So the input lines of your code become :

```
startingnumber1 = input('Enter your starting number:'))
endingnumber = input('Enter your ending number:')) + 1
```

Comment: I've rarely seen else used with a for loop.  I found this definition:  If the else statement is used with a for loop, the else statement is executed when the loop has exhausted iterating the list.  So it just tacks on some code after the loop ends.  But this doesn't solve the OP problem anyway.  Odd that it was upvoted

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want something really short, you could put `execfile(__file__)` at the end of your program.  You should probably do some error testing, however, so I would have it look more like this:

```
try:
    execfile(__file__)
except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError) as e:
    pass
```